# Using auto.arima on xts objects

Tags: r, xts

I'm trying to run `auto.arima` on some `xts` data, but am getting the following error:

```
library(quantmod)
library(forecast)

getSymbols('^GSPC',from='2000-01-01')
auto.arima(GSPC$GSPC.Close)

Error in dimnames(cd) <- list(as.character(index(x)), colnames(x)) : 
'dimnames' applied to non-array
```

I found that if I

```
close <- as.ts(GSPC$GSPC.Close)
```

then `auto.arima` does not return the error. But then I've lost the date information associated with the `xts` object. Is there a way to keep the data as `xts` and still run the function?

I noticed that e.g. `acf(GSPC$GPSC.Close)` and `pacf()` do not give errors.

Comment: If it doesn't work, don't use xts objects but export via `coredata()` to matrix, possibly convert with `as.data.frame()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you convert `GSPC$GSPC.Close` to a `ts`, `vector`, or `matrix` in the argument list of `auto.arima`:

```
auto.arima(as.ts(Cl(GSPC)))
auto.arima(coredata(Cl(GSPC)))  # Dirk's suggestion
```